# Display error while generating excel report using TestNG

Tags: selenium, testng, eclipse, excel

[image]I am trying to generate excel file for displaying TestNG report into excel sheet.

For that I created simple program for creating excel sheet and display static data, but it's displaying error

[image]

Comment: what's error ??

Comment: please check screenshot

Comment: image is not visible :(

Comment: please check now

Comment: Please show your reference jar files. Also show your import statement

Comment: Have you added this all jars in build path ? and also check the import statement

Comment: yes i have add in build path

Comment: @rutvi also check this link http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/java-code-to-convert-xlsx-to-csv-files/ Please add xlsx file as input

Comment: @rutvi clean your project and re-run project

Comment: i have try but not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50135/discussion-between-sagar007-and-rutvi-soni).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am following this steps and it is running fine.

**1. Need below jar files :**

- poi-3.9-20121203.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar

**2. Use JRE 7 and Higher**

**3. Write following code for it as under :**

`import java.io.File;`

`import java.io.FileOutputStream;`

`import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;`

`import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;`

`import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;`

`import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;`

```
public class WriteData
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
            XSSFSheet sh1 = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");
            Row row = sh1.createRow(0);
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue("Selenium");
            try
            {
                //Write the workbook in file system
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("E:\\Data.xls"));
                wb.write(out);
                out.close();
                System.out.println("written successfully on disk.");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note : Do not use jxl jar and imports.**